# How do I extract text of a single HTML element by tag name using MSXML in VBA?

Tags: html, vba, msxml, msxml6

I'm trying to extract US Patent titles using MSXML6.

On the full-text html view of a patent document on the USPTO website, the patent title appears as the first and only "font" element that is a child of "body".

Here is my function that is not working (I get no error; the cell with the formula just stays blank).

Can somebody help me figure out what is wrong?

An example URL that I am feeding into the function is http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=6293874.PN.&OS=PN/6293874&RS=PN/6293874

```
Function getUSPatentTitle(url As String)
    Static colTitle As New Collection
    Dim title As String
    Dim pageSource As String

    Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim xNode As IXMLDOMNode

    On Error Resume Next

    title = colTitle(url)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set html_doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML6.XMLHTTP60")

        xml_obj.Open "GET", url, False
        xml_obj.send
        pageSource = xml_obj.responseText
        Set xml_obj = Nothing

        Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
        If Not xDoc.LoadXML(pageSource) Then  
            Err.Raise xDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xDoc.parseError.reason
        End If

        Set xNode = xDoc.getElementsByTagName("font").Item(1)

        title = xNode.Text
        If Not title = "" Then colTitle.Add Item:=title, Key:=url
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0 ' I understand "GoTo" is dangerous coding but copied from somebody and so far haven't thought of a more natural substitute for a GoTo statement

    getUSPatentTitle = title
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few points:

- "On Error Goto 0" is not really a traditional Goto statement - it's just how you turn off user error handling in VBA. There were a few errors in your code but the "On Error Resume Next" skipped them so you saw nothing.
- The data from the web page is in HTML format not XML.
- There were a few "font" elements before the one with the title.

This should work:

```
Function getUSPatentTitle(url As String)
    Static colTitle As New Collection
    Dim title As String
    Dim pageSource As String
    Dim errorNumber As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    title = colTitle(url)
    errorNumber = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0

    If errorNumber <> 0 Then
        Dim xml_obj As XMLHTTP60
        Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        xml_obj.Open "GET", url, False
        xml_obj.send
        pageSource = xml_obj.responseText
        Set xml_obj = Nothing

        Dim html_doc As HTMLDocument
        Set html_doc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        html_doc.body.innerHTML = pageSource

        Dim fontElement As IHTMLElement
        Set fontElement = html_doc.getElementsByTagName("font").Item(3)

        title = fontElement.innerText
        If Not title = "" Then colTitle.Add Item:=title, Key:=url
    End If

    getUSPatentTitle = title
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks codersl - I had to add a reference: Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library, and it works.  I knew there were earler "font" elements but had been trying to find the first one directly under "body" and forgot to change the index.  Also I see it is apparently zero-based.  Is there not a "select" method in VBA analogous to the Jsoup method in Java where I could say something like `Element element = Document.select("html > body > font").get(0) ` ?  In this case that would work better because sometimes there may be one more "font" element above the title, but inside a table.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of an equivalent "select" method in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS selector:**

You can re-write what you described, which in fact is first `font` tag within a `body` tag as a CSS selector of:

```
body > font
```

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS selector]

---

**VBA:**

As it is the first match/only you want you can use the `querySelector` method of `document` to apply the selector and retrieve a single element.

```
Debug.Print html_doc.querySelector("body > font").innerText
```

You may need to add a reference to `HTML Object Library` and use an early bound call of `Dim html_doc As HTMLDocument` to access the method. The late bound method may expose the `querySelector` method but if the interface doesn't then use early binding.